# Regular expression find and replace in Adobe Dreamweaver

Tags: replace, expression, dreamweaver

I need to find the value of these variables `id, type, quality` and `name` in each of these strings beginning with braces `{ ... },` and use with `$1, $2, $3, $4` in replace textarea in Dreamweaver

For example, two original rows:

`{"id":999,"image":"NEW1_018","set":3,"quality":1,"icon":"inv_misc_ticket_tarot_beasts_01","type":4,"cost":2,"attack":2,"health":3,"race":23,"collectible":1,"name":"Bloodsail Raider","description":"Battlecry: Gain Attack equal to the Attack of your weapon.",popularity:919},
    {"id":749,"image":"EX1_012","set":3,"icon":"inv_misc_ticket_tarot_beasts_01","type":4,"faction":3,"quality":5,"cost":2,"attack":1,"health":1,"elite":1,"collectible":1,"name":"Bloodmage Thalnos","description":"Spell Damage +1. Deathrattle: Draw a card.",popularity:1538},`

But if I use `{"id":(.*?),(.*?)type":(.*?),(.*?)quality":(.*?),(.*?)name":"(.*?)"(.*?)},` in find textarea in Dreamweaver, it sometimes select more then 1 row, why?

What I doing wrong?

Thanks

Edit: values ​​`id, type, quality` and `name` between the parentheses will always be there other values ​​may or may not

Comment: I'm just an amateur, if someone can write a regular expression the required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Dreamweaver but you can try to match line beginning and end explicitly:

```
^{"id":([^,]*?),(.*?)((type":([^,]*?),(.*?)quality":([^,]*?))|((.*?)quality":([^,]*?),type":([^,]*?))),(.*?)name":"([^,]*?)"(.*?)},$
```

Comment: thanks, same problem, sometimes select 2 rows, but maybe I know problem, sometimes is quality before type, you know what i mean? can you fix it please?

Comment: I just tried use `( | )` so example: `{"id":(.*?),(.*?)(type":(.*?),(.*?)quality":(.*?)|quality":(.*?),(.*?)type":(.*?)),(.*?)name":"(.*?)"(.*?)},` this works fine, and select just one row, but how can I get just value from `id, quality, type and name` with `$1, $2` etc.?

Comment: That's a good approach...I did the same in my edit now. You only have more groups there so you'd have to skip some numbers..and you'll probably need to use named groups: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html but you'll have to try yourself if Dreamweaver supports this feature.

Comment: You should also replace your `.*` with `[^,]*`

Comment: probably dreamweaver dont support grups, but I can use http://www.regexr.com/ ... so can you please edit it again with grups? thanks